# How to select files from folder A that are not in Folder B using Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

My question is how could I print the name of the file from Folder A that are not existing in Folder B given that they have *different* file extensions.

Files from Folder A have `.xlsx` file extension and files from Folder B have `.txt` file extension.

Here is a visual representation:

[image]

**Folder A has 3 .xlsx files.**

[image]

**Folder B has 2 .txt files.**

My desired output is to print the `GHI.xlsx` filename since it does not exist in folder B.

Here is what I'm currently working at:

```
#Get list of files
$Files = Get-ChildItem '\C:\My Documents\Folder A\*.xlsm' `
    -Exclude 'C:\My Documents\Folder B\*.txt'

foreach($File in $Files) {
    $Filename = $File.BaseName
    echo  $Filename
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the `BaseName` property  using the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) cmdlet:

```
$folderA = Get-ChildItem 'C:\My Documents\Folder A' -File
$folderB = Get-ChildItem 'C:\My Documents\Folder B' -File | 
   select -ExpandProperty BaseName)

$folderA | Where-Object BaseName -NotIn $folderB | 
    select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: Totally missed that requirement, I'll get some more coffee ... : )

Comment: @sodawillow It always happens to me too ;-)

Comment: @MichelleSantos I updated my answer to improove the performance, you may try this. Thanks for the accept.

Comment: @MartinBrandl Thanks a lot that would definitely help since I would be dealing with a lot of files .